# How to insert machine instruction using BuildMI() correctly inside a MachineFunctionPass in LLVM?

Tags: c++, linux, llvm, riscv

I wrote my MachineFunctionPass following this blog: https://www.kharghoshal.xyz/blog/writing-machinefunctionpass

Then ported it for RISCV target. It was working well.
I also add iteration for each instruction to check for Call instruction. It still working, until I tried to write instruction.

This is my MachineFunctionPass:

```
#include "RISCV.h"
#include "RISCVInstrInfo.h"
#include "llvm/CodeGen/MachineFunctionPass.h"
#include "llvm/CodeGen/MachineInstrBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/CodeGen/TargetRegisterInfo.h"

using namespace llvm;

#define RISCV_MACHINEINSTR_PRINTER_PASS_NAME                                   \
  "Dummy RISCV machineinstr printer pass"

namespace {

class RISCVMachineInstrPrinter : public MachineFunctionPass {
public:
  static char ID;

  RISCVMachineInstrPrinter() : MachineFunctionPass(ID) {
    initializeRISCVMachineInstrPrinterPass(*PassRegistry::getPassRegistry());
  }

  bool runOnMachineFunction(MachineFunction &MF) override;

  StringRef getPassName() const override {
    return RISCV_MACHINEINSTR_PRINTER_PASS_NAME;
  }
};

char RISCVMachineInstrPrinter::ID = 0;

bool RISCVMachineInstrPrinter::runOnMachineFunction(MachineFunction &MF) {

  for (auto &MBB : MF) {
    
    for (auto &MI : MBB) {

      if (MI.isCall()) {
        outs() << "Found Call\n";

        outs() << MI.getOpcode() << "\n";

        RISCVInstrInfo *XII; // target instruction info
        DebugLoc DL;
        MachineBasicBlock::iterator MBBI = BuildMI(MBB, MI ,DL, XII->get(RISCV::SW), RISCV::X1)
            .addReg(RISCV::X31)
            .addImm(0);
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}

} // end of anonymous namespace

INITIALIZE_PASS(RISCVMachineInstrPrinter, "RISCV-machineinstr-printer",
                RISCV_MACHINEINSTR_PRINTER_PASS_NAME,
                true, // is CFG only?
                true  // is analysis?
)

namespace llvm {

FunctionPass *createRISCVMachineInstrPrinterPass() {
  return new RISCVMachineInstrPrinter();
}

} // namespace llvm
```

When I tried to compile my code using

```
clang hi.c -o hi -march=rv32g --target=riscv32
```

The output was an error message that I do not understand:

```
Found Call
202
PLEASE submit a bug report to https://bugs.llvm.org/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12 -cc1 -triple riscv32-- -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name hi.c -mrelocation-model static -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -nostdsysteminc -target-feature +m -target-feature +a -target-feature +f -target-feature +d -target-feature +relax -target-feature -save-restore -target-abi ilp32d -msmall-data-limit 8 -fno-split-dwarf-inlining -debugger-tuning=gdb -resource-dir /home/ibndias/riscv32/lib/clang/12.0.0 -isysroot /home/ibndias/riscv32/riscv32-unknown-elf -internal-isystem /home/ibndias/riscv32/riscv32-unknown-elf/include -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/ibndias/Documents/Projects -ferror-limit 19 -fno-signed-char -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o /tmp/hi-047c57.o -x c hi.c 
1.  <eof> parser at end of file
2.  Code generation
3.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module 'hi.c'.
4.  Running pass 'Dummy RISCV machineinstr printer pass' on function '@main'
 #0 0x000055c4c194489e llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0x185589e)
 #1 0x000055c4c1942734 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0x1853734)
 #2 0x000055c4c1942878 SignalHandler(int) (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0x1853878)
 #3 0x00007f3f492a23c0 __restore_rt (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+0x153c0)
 #4 0x000055c4c0b72ae2 (anonymous namespace)::RISCVMachineInstrPrinter::runOnMachineFunction(llvm::MachineFunction&) (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0xa83ae2)
 #5 0x000055c4c0e8901c llvm::MachineFunctionPass::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0xd9a01c)
 #6 0x000055c4c12ca770 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0x11db770)
 #7 0x000055c4c12cbd79 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0x11dcd79)
 #8 0x000055c4c12c9980 llvm::legacy::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&) (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0x11da980)
 #9 0x000055c4c1be7b26 (anonymous namespace)::EmitAssemblyHelper::EmitAssembly(clang::BackendAction, std::unique_ptr<llvm::raw_pwrite_stream, std::default_delete<llvm::raw_pwrite_stream> >) (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0x1af8b26)
#10 0x000055c4c1be94ce clang::EmitBackendOutput(clang::DiagnosticsEngine&, clang::HeaderSearchOptions const&, clang::CodeGenOptions const&, clang::TargetOptions const&, clang::LangOptions const&, llvm::DataLayout const&, llvm::Module*, clang::BackendAction, std::unique_ptr<llvm::raw_pwrite_stream, std::default_delete<llvm::raw_pwrite_stream> >) (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0x1afa4ce)
#11 0x000055c4c2863fd1 clang::BackendConsumer::HandleTranslationUnit(clang::ASTContext&) (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0x2774fd1)
#12 0x000055c4c360db39 clang::ParseAST(clang::Sema&, bool, bool) (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0x351eb39)
#13 0x000055c4c21fb239 clang::FrontendAction::Execute() (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0x210c239)
#14 0x000055c4c21af54b clang::CompilerInstance::ExecuteAction(clang::FrontendAction&) (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0x20c054b)
#15 0x000055c4c22cd800 clang::ExecuteCompilerInvocation(clang::CompilerInstance*) (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0x21de800)
#16 0x000055c4c0b1ca57 cc1_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0xa2da57)
#17 0x000055c4c0b1a60b ExecuteCC1Tool(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<char const*>&) (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0xa2b60b)
#18 0x000055c4c0ab1cde main (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0x9c2cde)
#19 0x00007f3f48d530b3 __libc_start_main /build/glibc-YYA7BZ/glibc-2.31/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:342:3
#20 0x000055c4c0b1a19e _start (/home/ibndias/riscv32/bin/clang-12+0xa2b19e)
clang-12: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
clang-12: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
clang version 12.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git 99ad956fdaee5398fdcf46fa49cb433cf52dc461)
Target: riscv32--
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/ibndias/riscv32/bin
clang-12: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang-12: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/hi-5c6fca.c
clang-12: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/hi-5c6fca.sh
clang-12: note: diagnostic msg: 

********************
```

And this is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int foo(int a, int b)
{
        return a + b;
}

int main()
{
        int a, b, c;

        a = 0x10;
        b = 0x20;

        c = foo(a,b);
        return c;
}
```

Is this a correct way to insert instruction?

```
  for (auto &MBB : MF) {

    for (auto &MI : MBB) {

      if (MI.isCall()) {
        outs() << "Found Call\n";

        outs() << MI.getOpcode() << "\n";

        RISCVInstrInfo *XII; // target instruction info
        DebugLoc DL;
        MachineBasicBlock::iterator MBBI = BuildMI(MBB, MI ,DL, XII->get(RISCV::SW), RISCV::X1)
            .addReg(RISCV::X31)
            .addImm(0);
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using MBBI to give the position to the buildMI while it is not yet initialized.
what I understand is that you want to add an instruction before the call so you should use MI instead of MBBI as the second parameter.
The target instruction info (XII) is not initialized also.
You can take a look here:
https://llvm.org/docs/CodeGenerator.html#id23

Comment: XII is not initialized too.

Comment: Ah, yes I missed that. I changed the `RISCVInstrInfo *XII;` to `const TargetInstrInfo *XII = MF.getSubtarget().getInstrInfo();` It's working now, thank you!